# R xts - How to add data to xts object after initializing with zero width

Tags: r, xts

I need to declare an xts variable before a for loop and then add elements to it inside the for loop. My implementation is not working. The code below works if I declare before for loop as xtsvar <-xts(13.2, as.Date("2013-04-07","%Y-%m-%d")) instead of xtsvar <- xts(). Unfortunately, I can't do this as I can't enter some dummy value that I can't remove later.

```
xtsvar <- xts()
for (i in seq (2, 10))
 ....
 ....
 xtsvar <- rbind(xtsvar, xts(13.2, as.Date("2013-04-07","%Y-%m-%d")))
 ....

 .....
```

Note: Inside the for loop I tried xtsvar <- xts(13.2, as.Date("2013-04-07","%Y-%m-%d"))) in the first iteration and rbind in the further iteration. It failed in the first iteration)

Comment: I would have though adding a column would first be done outside the loop (perhaps with `cbind`)  and then add rows with `rbind`.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always a bad idea to add one record at a time to an `xts` or `data.frame` object. There are often better ways to create the data all at once. Without knowing what you're doing in the loop, it's hard to suggest alternatives, but at the very least, you'll be better off first building your data by columns and then converting to `xts` at the very end.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. 

I was doing what you suggested. Read data in a list but struggling to put this from list to xts 

e.g. ibmstckprclst[date] = 35.5. Let us say the length of the list is 100 (100 dates and price). The dates are in string format. Now, I have to put this data in xts with date as index (need to convert the date from string to Date prior to loading in to the xts). Any help will be appreciate

I have another post titled "R time series and data frame object from reading a non standard file" that gives more information on what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it in this way: first of all, initialize xtsvar with at least a row, for example:

```
xtsvar <- xts(13.2,as.Date("2013-04-07","%Y-%m-%d"))
```

instead of

```
xtsvar <- xts()
```

After that, you can add a row in this way:

```
xtsvar <- c(xtsvar,xts(15,as.Date("2013-04-08","%Y-%m-%d")))
```

More in general, if you have more than one column:

```
xtsvar <- c(xtsvar,xts(matrix(c(1,2,2,5),nrow=1),as.Date("2013-04-08","%Y-%m-%d")))
```